# Nginx url domain redirect

Tags: unix, redirect, nginx

With nginx, I would like to configure a redirect between two domains like this:

`domainA.com/<anypath>` to `domainB.com/redirect/<anypath>`

My code right now:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name .domainA.org(.*)$;
    rewrite ^ http://domainB.org/redirect$1?;
}
```

The redirect from domainA to domainB works, but it doesn't include `/redirect` in the new path.  Any help is appreciated! thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx has some built-in functionality to handle this for you. Try this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domainA.org;
    return 301 http://domainB.org/redirect$request_uri;
}
```